# Monomorphisms and epimorphisms in a homotopy category

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory

What do the epimorphisms and mononomorphisms look like in the homotopy category of $CW-$complexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a difficult question to handle in full generality, but suffice it to say there aren't all that many. Hilton and Roitberg in their *Note on Monomorphisms and Epimorphisms in Homotopy Theory* give a sort of Cantor-Bernstein-Schroder theorem: under finiteness conditions, if $X$ and $Y$ admit epis in both directions, then they are equivalent, while if $X$ and $Y$ admit monos in both directions then they are equivalent up to coverings. You can find a few papers on the topic by Googling around, but most efforts seem to have gone to prove that the homotopy category is balanced, which is a relatively novel result; it seems beyond mortal ken to really understand the monos and epis fully. It is worth noting that monos and epis in *stable* homotopy are totally trivial-in any triangulated category, such as that of spectra, all monos and epis are split.