What are the monomorphisms in $\mathbf{hTop}$?
Consider the category of topological spaces with morphisms being homotopy classes of continuous functions. What are the monomorphisms and regular monomorphisms of this category? Does anyone have examples or counterexamples?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here're some items that could add context to your post: 1) an explanation that classifying mono/epi/regular morphisms in a category is a standard thing to do in category theory (perhaps with definitions of each of these); 2) a reference to the solution of the problem in easier cases (for instance, the standard topological category); 3) an explanation of your background (I'm guessing this is "I am relatively new to homotopy theory and I'm curious about this", but I don't know). I think this is a natural question to ask which should be answered here, and these additions will help with that.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3587663/monomorphisms-and-epimorphisms-in-a-homotopy-category

I am not aware of a classification right now, but since you have asked for examples as well:
A monomorphism in $\mathbf{Top}$ doesn't have to be* a monomorphism in $\mathbf{hTop}$: If $h : X \to Y$ is a monomorphism in $\mathbf{hTop}$, then $h_* : \hom_{\mathbf{hTop}}(\{\ast\},X) \to \hom_{\mathbf{hTop}}(\{\ast\},Y)$ is injective, meaning: if there are two points $a,b \in X$ for which there is a path $h(a) \leadsto h(b)$, then there is a path $a \leadsto b$. So for example, the inclusion $\{\ast\} \sqcup \{\ast\} = \{0,1\} \hookrightarrow [0,1]$ is a monomorphism in $\mathbf{Top}$, but it* is not in $\mathbf{hTop}$.
More generally, if $h : X \to Y$ is a monomorphism in $\mathbf{hTop}_*$ (we need a base point), then for every $n$ the induced homomorphism on the homotopy groups $h_* : \pi_n(X) \to \pi_n(Y)$ is injective.
There are also lots of examples of non-monomorphisms in $\mathbf{Top}$ which are* monomorphisms in $\mathbf{hTop}$. Take two contractible spaces $X,Y$ and any continuous map $f : X \to Y$. Then $f$ is not necessarily a monomorphism in $\mathbf{Top}$, but it's* an isomorphism in $\mathbf{hTop}$. A concrete example is the constant map $[0,1] \to [0,1]$, $x \mapsto 0$.
Every morphism of the form $\{\ast\} \to Y$ is a monomorphism both in $\mathbf{Top}$ and $\mathbf{hTop}$ (for trivial reasons).
If $i : A \hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion of a subspace which is a retract (up to homotopy), then $i$ is just a split monomorphism in $\mathbf{hTop}$, hence a monomorphism (even a regular one). So for example, $S^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ is a (split) monomorphism in $\mathbf{hTop}$.
*Formally, I mean of course the homotopy class of the continuous map.

"There are also lots of examples of monomorphisms in hTop which aren't monomorphisms in Top" <-- That's a rather weird statements. Technically doesn't even make much sense. How you get from hTop morphisms to Top morphisms? Picking a representative at random? Then surely a hTop monomorphism $[0,1]\to [0,1]$ can be represented by a monomorphism in Top. A proper example would be a monomorphism $[0,1]\to {*}$.

You are right. Will fix that.
